# Checkboxes all ticked, Do something?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I'm just looking for a bit of help on the best way to do this..

So I have a sample SQL Database:

[image: Sample SQL Database]

Now from that DB I have a PHP page to show checkboxes ticked if there is a "1" in the corresponding checkbox field.

[image: Checkboxes]

What I would now like to do is:

Once both checkboxes are ticked, I would like to display a 5 second timer or a message, something of that nature, but how do I ascertain if the boxes have both been checked?

I'm guessing I would have to run a query against the whole table and work from the variable I get back?

Answer (score 4):

you may use change events

```
var i = 1, interval, timeout;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){

   if ($('input[type=checkbox]').length ==   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
       $('div').show();
       interval = window.setInterval(
         function() {
           $('div').text(i++);
         },
         1000
       );
       timeout = window.setTimeout(
         function(){
           document.location = 'http://google.com/';
         },
       5000);
   }
  else {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    $('div').hide().text('0');
    i = 1;
  }
});
```

example to edit http://jsbin.com/uwofus/11/edit
example to test http://jsbin.com/uwofus/11

Comment: updated, it is quite simple using core JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: hi i was kind wanting it to countdown 5 4 3 2 1 once they were all ticked then goto www.google.com (for example) ..thanks for your help wonderfull

Comment: here you go, as a homework try to hash some variables for better performance :)

Comment: If i untick a box it doesn't stop the counter though but i guess i never stated that , i can definately build off this

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with jQuery, so I'm assuming you want to do the check in the browser, and not in the database.

```
if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").size() == 2) {
   //both boxes are checked
   //display message/start timer here
} else {
   //not all boxes are checked
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..im looking for the best option id like to maybe check the DB if its not too much work?

Answer (score 0):

You could give your checkboxes a class e.g. `mycb`, then count the number checked:

```
$('.mycb').change(function(){

    if($('.mycb').size() == $('.mydb:checked').size())
    {
        // all checkboxes are checked - do something
    }

});
```